# Can I trigger a form action after selecting an image file for upload?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I currently have a form that lets a user select an image.  After the image has been selected they need to click the submit button. I'm using jquery so the call ends up looking like this:

```
$('#image_form').ajaxForm(function(data) { 
   // do some stuff
});
```

here is the HTML:

```
<form id="image_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="load_photo.php" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8000000" />

    <table>    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="mapimage">Select an image:</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="file" type="file" id="file"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update_photo" id="update_photo"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Is it possible to trigger this form action after a user has browsed to a photo and selected it? Ideally they would not have to click the submit button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a file has been selected, the `change` event fires on the `input[type=file]` element, so just listen for that.

```
$('#file').change(function(e){
    // do something after a file is selected
    // maybe submit the file?
    e.target.form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above you can bind the `change` event, however you cannot detect what file they have selected or even the name of that file in some browsers *cough* older ie's I believe *cough*.

What you can do is to get the name of the file (`$("#fileinput").val()`) then parse the string at the last period:

```
// on change
{
    var fileParts = $("#fileinput").val().split(".");
    var extension = fileParts[fileParts.length - 1];
    var validFileExt = new Array("jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif");
    var isImage = jQuery.inArray(extension, validFileExt);
    if (isImage){
        // submit
    }
}
```

*BTW I just made up that code so dbl check it*

Of course you still need to offer a traditional button for **Those** browsers.

Also, this is not a valid file validation ;)